# How to Zip Blob value(PDF) in Java

Tags: java, blob

I have a PDF stored in Database as blob. I have a usecase to retrieve the blob file(PDF) and zip it using java. Could anybody help me out here?

Below is my sample code. Where I get my pdf from database as BLobDomain
I want it inside a blobfolder and i have given the representation below 807.pdf and 1285.pdf .
Thats how i want my blobdomain values to be

```
 BlobDomain doc1=(BlobDomain)rowshis[0].getAttribute("Document");

 BlobDomain doc2=(BlobDomain)rowshis[1].getAttribute("Document");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("Test Date");
        System.out.println("check----1");

        File f = new File("/customer/scratch/HDLtest.zip");
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(newFileOutputStream(f));
        System.out.println("check----2");

        ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry("BlobFiles/807.pdf");
        out.putNextEntry(e);
        ZipEntry e11 = new ZipEntry("BlobFiles/1285.pdf");
        out.putNextEntry(e11);
        System.out.println("check----3");
        ZipEntry e1 = new ZipEntry("Test.dat");
        out.putNextEntry(e1);
        System.out.println("check----4");

        byte[] data = sb.toString().getBytes();
        out.write(data, 0, data.length);
        out.closeEntry();
        out.close();
```

Comment: I had read many times (a make edit of punctuation). What is exactly Your question?

Comment: i retrieved 2 pdf from my database in to doc1 and doc2 which is of blob domain and i Need that to be zipped as pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the content of a zip entry before adding the next zip entry.

Call sequence should be:

- [`putNextEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#putNextEntry(java.util.zip.ZipEntry)) - *Begins writing a new ZIP file entry and positions the stream to the start of the entry data. Closes the current entry if still active.*
- [`write()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#write(byte%5B%5D,int,int)) - *Writes an array of bytes to the current ZIP entry data.*
- [`closeEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#closeEntry()) - *Closes the current ZIP entry and positions the stream for writing the next entry.*
  This call is optional, since calling `putNextEntry()` for the next entry automatically closes the current entry if still active.

Repeat above for each entry you want to add to the zip file.